# How to convert register contents to something readable similar to :register command?

Tags: vimscript, register

Let's assume there is a macro stored in register 'r'

I can obtain the contents of this register by executing `getreg('r')`, but if I print this then it can often be unreadable.

I noticed though that if I execute `:registers` that the contents of the 'r' register is displayed in a readable format.

Is there a way to do this without calling `:registers`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to put the register contents in a buffer use Normal mode command sequence `"rp`. That'll produce the same thing as you'd see with `:reg r`.

The thing with `getreg()` is that it doesn't attempt to output printable characters. For example, if register "r" contains a backspace and you send `getreg('r')` output to a buffer (e.g. with `<C-R>=getreg('r')` while in Insert mode) then the backspace will actually move the cursor back. 
But if you paste the register directly you'll see printable translations of everything. (Example: for me backspace is displayed as `<80>kb`.)

Note that there is a function that does similar translation to printable characters on whatever you pass to it called `strtrans()`. Modifying the Insert mode command mentioned above to be `<C-R>=strtrans(getreg('r'))` will display the same thing as `"rp`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but yes you are right, the `strtrans` function is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: No worries. It seemed at first like you were looking for `"rp` but everyone beyond beginner knows that, right? Remembering `strtrans()`, though, and I was pretty sure I had what you were looking for one way or the other.